# Dynamically fetching user credentials for authenticating with ADLS from a spark job

Tags: authentication, apache-spark, credentials, azure-data-lake, credential-providers

Is there a way I can fetch user credentials to authenticate with ADLS from within a spark job. I am trying to write a library that be used by users in their spark job to read data and want to hide implementation details. Also, what would be the best way to get credentials for a user from within spark job?

Answer (score 0):

You can't fetch user credentials. You'll either need to save the user login session (tokens) somewhere securely, or...

If you want to have your solution authenticate without any interaction from an end user, then using a service principal + a certificate or key is the right way to go. This means your application will log in as the service principal, rather than as a user, and that service principal will need permissions on the resources and data upon which your solution should operate.

Azure Active Directory is what you'll authenticate with in either case, and their documentation for their authentication libraries is [located here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries). They have a REST API, SDKs in many languages, and I'm sure there are third-party libraries are also available, if your language of choice isn't covered yet.

I hope this helps!